# Dynamics 365 Webhook Json Remote execution context sent with German characters as rubbish

Tags: dynamics-crm, webhooks, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, power-automate

Using Plugin Registration, I registered webhook, Power automate and [sample webhook](https://webhook.site/) as well.

Json (Remote execution context) sent to webhook seems to be fine but when German characters appears in field values, it sends as rubbish.

I tried adding httpheader to webhook as `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` or `Accept-Charset: utf-8`
but this did not helped.
Did anyone previously faced similar issue?
I suspect there is bug from Dynamics-crm side especially plugin registration tool, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IServiceEndpointNotificationService](https://arifdynamiccrm.wordpress.com/2019/01/19/webhooks-in-microsoft-dynamics-365/) to encode the content before sending or alternatively what you can do is creating an [Azure Function](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2018/07/15/dynamics-365-using-webhooks-to-post-data-from-plugin-to-azure-function/) that you will invoke on your Webhook and inside the function you should encode the content to UTF-8 and make a second call to you final endpoint, you can do there also further transformation of data if needed.

Comment: both the methods mentioned seems to be fairly relevant, however I had a call with Microsoft and indeed there is an bug when sending webhook request from Dynamics.So even if you use Azure you will end up with rubish.

Comment: I work with german content and I was able to have this fixed using IServiceEndpointNotificationService

Comment: can I add further question, how can I use `IserviceEndpoint` before seding the data/context to Webhook. As far as I see, PRT has Webhook and then Message step. This message sends to webhook without any chance of using `IserviceEndpoint`